# How to detect ECU's NM Messages in CAN remote wakeup?

Tags: embedded, can-bus, autosar, pdu, automotive

I am trying to implement the remote wakeup scenario in CAN network with Infotainment ECU. I am currently referring this AUTOSAR Network management document for the implementation
https://www.autosar.org/fileadmin/user_upload/standards/foundation/19-11/AUTOSAR_PRS_NetworkManagementProtocol.pdf

I need some clarification about CAN NM message state for checking the remote wakeup in complex device driver (CDD) components. I have 2 channel in Infotainment ECU that are `CAN FD` and `HSCAN`. I have configured `PNC` (Partial Networking) in `HSCAN` channel.
So my idea is to implement the remote wakeup of Infotainment ECU by checking the NM state from "`CanNm_GetState`" API directly. As per the AUTOSAR specification, `CanNm_GetState` API Returns the
`state` and the `mode` of the network management from `CANM` Module.

**My idea is like this:**

Suppose Infotainment ECU is in sleep state and Other ECU's required Network active request, then Infotainment ECU get CAN `NM message` from other ECU. So `CANNM` module in AUTOSAR will  update the CAN `NM` state based on the received `PNC` ID.

During this time, my `CDD` (Complex device driver component) can get either 4 state through  `CanNm_GetState()` API.

```
NM Mode=> "Network Mode"
NM Mode => "Prepare Bus-Sleep Mode"
NM Mode => "Bus-Sleep Mode"
```

As per AUTOSAR specification, Network mode contains `Repeat message state`, `Normal operation state` and `Ready sleep state`.

So as per the `AUTOSAR` Network management document, I have understood that

`Inactive` Mode are `Bus Sleep`, `Prepare Bus Sleep`.
`Active` Mode are `Repeat Message State`, `Normal operation State` and `Ready Sleep State`.

Now I want to clarify below questions:

1. What will be the NM state (`CanNm_GetState` return value) if we enable the Application messages of `HSCAN` messages in CAN ? Will `NM` state updated by `CANM` during this time (`local wakeup with application messages`) ?
2. If Infotaiment ECU want to wakeup during remote wakeup request (With valid PNC ID), should I only check `Ready sleep` state of `CANM` using `CanNm_GetState` API ?

I hope my understandings are correct and your help will be appreciated.